# Using tilemaps for an isometric football game with cocos2dx

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, isometric, tilemap

I am writing a simple soccer game in cocos2d-x and recently found out that older iOS versions do not support cocos2d sprites larger than 1024x1024px.

I was thinking about using isometric tilemaps to create a larger football field.

Is this the way to go ? If so, how can i convert a  convert my 2048x2048px football field image into several isometric tiles ?

Comment: Just FYI: The texture size limitation has nothing to do with the iOS version. It's a limitation imposed by the GPU. Here's the corresponding [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/3DDrawing/Conceptual/OpenGLES_ProgrammingGuide/OpenGLESPlatforms/OpenGLESPlatforms.html). The PowerVR MBX GPU (iPhone, iPhone 3G and 1st and 2nd generation iPod touch) can have 1024x1024 max. texture size. Basically all newer devices support up to 2048x2048.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to cut your image into tiles and then use individual images depending on what your screen is showing to the user then you should use Tile Cutter provided by "JEFF LAMARCHE" by following this link,

http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.in/2010/10/tile-cutter-updated_30.html

Also if you want to use one of your images that contains all the sprite used by the game then use Tiled Map Editor,

http://www.mapeditor.org/